# How to run OxiPNG with launchd and WatchPaths?

Tags: command-line, launchd, screen-capture

I want to run `oxipng *.png` in `/Users/user/Desktop/` immediately after a PNG screenshot (Cmd-Shift-3) is created in my Desktop folder.

I have the following `plist` file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>oxipng</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>oxipng</string>
        <string>*.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/user/Desktop/</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then, I run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/oxipng.plist`. However, the PNG are never modified after creation.

---

How do I make oxipng run after a screenshot is saved to the Desktop folder?

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are expanded by shells only, so your plist just passes `*.png` to `oxipng`, a file which clearly doesn‘t exist. Create a shell script (which then runs `cd ~/Desktop; oxipng *.png`) and use launchd to trigger that.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the corresponding plist? I tried to run a `.sh` from the plist file, but it didn't do anything really.

Comment: @homocomputeris The same as the one you have, but with the shell script instead of oxipng. Ah, and use the full path (not just the name of the binary), otherwise it will for sure not work.